# LVM: How do I make use of a Logical Volume?

Tags: lvm

I installed Proxmox 5.4 and this is how it setup my logical volumes:

```
 --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pve/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                pve
  LV UUID                AmJwba-alii-Uqkw-XHAy-ka2g-EIeQ-l7jlw3
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time proxmox, 2020-04-24 16:38:41 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                8.00 GiB
  Current LE             2048
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pve/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                pve
  LV UUID                Wd0A6l-qmKA-EUz1-oxzZ-nILJ-FGfe-xtEuji
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time proxmox, 2020-04-24 16:38:41 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                96.00 GiB
  Current LE             24576
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                data
  VG Name                pve
  LV UUID                e20Iqk-sRI2-KsGF-FW5b-KUtR-Pp5C-j6CJVe
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time proxmox, 2020-04-24 16:38:42 +0100
  LV Pool metadata       data_tmeta
  LV Pool data           data_tdata
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                794.79 GiB
  Allocated pool data    0.00%
  Allocated metadata     0.04%
  Current LE             203466
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:4
```

I want to make use of the LV called "data" but I don't know how to create a filesystem on this since there is no path associated. Is there another LVM command I need to map this to a device?

Comment: I would say just go for `/dev/pve/data` as device, however, it looks like the only volume with metadata. how was it created ? Is this a "real" host/VM or a container ?

Answer (score 2):

The `data` LV appears to be a [thinpool LV](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Storage:_LVM_Thin). It's an additional layer between the VG and the final LV. It allows additional features (eg: overprovisionning or also efficient copy-on-write where performances don't decrease the more additional snapshots are made).

There's plenty of documentation available about it. For example the [lvmthin(7)](https://manpages.debian.org/lvm2/lvmthin.7) manpage describing the feature:

> Blocks in a standard lvm(8) Logical Volume (LV) are allocated when the
>   LV is created, but **blocks in a thin provisioned LV are allocated as
>   they are written**. Because of this, a thin provisioned LV is given a
>   virtual size, and **can then be much larger than physically available
>   storage**. The amount of physical storage provided for thin provisioned
>   LVs can be increased later as the need arises.
>
> Blocks in a standard LV are allocated (during creation) from the
>   Volume Group (VG), but blocks in a thin LV are allocated (during use)
>   from a special "thin pool LV". The thin pool LV contains blocks of
>   physical storage, and blocks in thin LVs just reference blocks in the
>   thin pool LV.
>
> **A thin pool LV must be created before thin LVs can be created within
>   it**. A thin pool LV is created by combining two standard LVs: a large
>   data LV that will hold blocks for thin LVs, and a metadata LV that
>   will hold metadata. The metadata tracks which data blocks belong to
>   each thin LV.

It's kept hidden under the hood, but the large data LV is `data_tdata` and the metadata LV is `data_tmeta`. To display them you can use `lvs --all` or `lvdisplay --all` (which will show `Internal LV Name`, telling it's not for direct use), but you can also forget about it, it's not really needed to know about this.

Anyway to use them, there's also a lot of documentation available around. For example at [Redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_logical_volumes/assembly_thinly-provisioned-logical-volumes_configuring-and-managing-logical-volumes):

> The following command uses the `-T` option of the `lvcreate` command to create a thin volume named thinvolume in the thin pool `vg001/mythinpool`. Note that in this case you are specifying virtual size, and that you are specifying a virtual size for the volume that is greater than the pool that contains it.
>
> ```
> # lvcreate -V 1G -T vg001/mythinpool -n thinvolume
> ```

So in your case to create a 100 terabytes thin provisionned logical volume (to show off the over-provisioning feature):

```
lvcreate -V 100T -T pve/data -n bigthinvolume
```

It will then be usable like other LVs, with slight differences when it comes to advanced features like snapshots.

Be careful with overprovisionning, once data% (or more rarely meta%), as displayed with [`lvs`](https://manpages.debian.org/lvm2/lvs.8) reaches 100% on a thinpool, any write that causes block allocation will fail, resulting in an I/O error in the layer above (the thin LV): you must increase available real size before this ever happens.

On a Debian-based system, the package [`thin-provisioning-tools`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/thin-provisioning-tools) should probably be installed, it might be needed to handle some thin provisioning advanced features, including at boot. I don't know where this applies with Proxmox.

Answer (score 1):

The LV "data" should be reserved for Proxmox VMs.
Try to create a VM on "data" and check logical volumes again.
BTW, you are not using the latest version of Proxmox.